# I would like to change my current switch to motion sensor switch, however, the switch is blocked by the washer. What is the easiest way to do this?

Tags: switch, motion-sensor

There are a couple of options I'm considering:

1. [Ceiling-Mount Occupancy Sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00192EUFY)
2. Change all the current light LED bulbs (g24d) to motion sensor bulbs. But I need to buy adapters (g24 to e27).
3. [Motion sensor ceiling light.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08V142B5B)

Is there a better way?
Thank you.

Comment: Since you haven't defined "best", it invites opinions and opinion based questions are explicitly off-topic. If you'd care to [edit] your question to indicate what "best" means to you, then it becomes something objective that we can supply an answer for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion FreeMan. I'm just looking for the easiest way to do this since I'm not experienced with electrical and wirings.

Comment: It depends on the size and shape of the room, number of doors, usage, and style of lighting.  You've told us you have multiple light fixtures, using G24D bulbs.  That rules out some easy options.  IS it a large room? What goes on in it besides laundry?  Is there more than one door?     It also depends on how the ceiling is wired. You may be able to put a motion sensor at the location of one of the existing lights and control them all.

Comment: if the switch is surface mount, you could easily raise it up over the washer.

Answer (score 2):

Use surface conduit to come off the existing switch box to a more appropriate location for a motion sensor.

Something like Legrand Wiremold will suffice.  A Surface Conduit Starter Box on top of the switch (which will push the switch out about an inch) and then their surface conduit to a location for a new junction box for the sensor.  Then a 2" deep box at that location.

This would also allow retaining the original switch; so either one will operate the light.